# How can I get the state of a child after it exited?

Tags: erlang

I am making a program where the child has certain values, but can receive a `die` message at any time making it exit. Additionally I have a monitoring process that links itself to the children to check whether they are still alive, trapping their exits. If a child has died, the monitor will get an exit message, re-register the child and re-spawn it if necessary with the same state/values. The monitor does this so all children can always be found by their registered names as if they were never down.

So my questions are:

- Since the parent trapped the child from exiting, will it still be able to contact the child after it exited, to get its current state? Or did the child exit regardless?
- How can I re-register the child with the same name and values? Should I keep a record of all children's values or is there another way to retrieve those values through some Erlang magic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you are reimplementing `supervisor`. If it is not because of educational purposes, just read about [supervision](http://www.erlang.org/doc/design_principles/sup_princ.html).

If you are just learning, then here is the answer. You wrote that "parent trapped child from exiting". Trapping exits doesn't work that way. Process can set `trap_exit` flag only for itself. It is used, when some other process tries to terminate it with `exit(Pid, Reason)`. Instead of dying, process which called `process_flag(trap_exit, true)` will receive a message. It may even ignore it and continue working.

For example, you can use this way: child is trapping exits and when someone tries to shut it down, it receives the message and calls `exit({Reason, State})`. This will ensure, that monitoring process gets the state of child with notification about it dying. Then it can respawn new process with inital state and re-register it.

To answer your questions: you can't contact process that exited. You have to spawn new process, feed the previous state and then register it again.

Comment: It is indeed for educational purposes (read: homework) and I implemented it the way you said by sending the state over the exit message. I do have to admit that it felt like a dirty hack than the way to go though... Or would this be the Erlang way? I have indeed a process telling the children to die and they have to call exit(killed), so I changed it to exit({killed,State}), but wasn't sure whether that would be the way to go.

Comment: It is hacky, because the homework asks you to do thing, that you shouldn't do. If process terminates, it means it either encountered an error (probably due to bad state), hangs and is killed from outside (possibly because of bad state) or is terminating normally, so the state won't be needed. You should never get state from exiting process, because it is probably wrong and can infect rest of your application.

Comment: Then assuming it crashed, how would I be able to recover the values of the child? Should the child constantly update its values to the parent?

Comment: It is good for processes to have single responsibility. Let parent be supervisor and only monitor and respawn dying children. It might be good idea to spawn siblings. One is responsible only for keeping state and second one for doing computation. If they are on different nodes (and nodes on different machines) - you have great fault tolerance. Before respawning any of them, you can contact the other to extract initial state.

Answer (score 1):

*will it still be able to contact the child after it exited* -> No. Once the process died, everything is cleaned by the erlang VM.

*How can I re-register the child with the same name* -> Yes, if the process really died, there is no constraint to re-use the same name for process registration. It is in fact the usual case.

*How can I re-register the child with the same values* -> No short answer.

- First you will be able to get the state of this process only if you register it in ets or mnesia or any external mean (external to your process) - You will get the last stored value
- Or if your process catches the die message and send back to its "home made supervisor" all needed information. It will introduce complexity in your design, and not all cause of die can be catched (at least the kill message cannot).
- Last: why doing this. it sounds that you should work on the data model of your application. There are some data that belong to your application, and that must survive to a process crash (customer account, order...). In most cases it should survive to the complete application stop or server crash. Data base (with replication ?) are made for this. These data are not process state. Process state, on the other end, should have meaning only for the current living process, it can be a socket, some references, pids, some timeout ... and you should take care to rebuild everything from init parameters, not trying to restore a previous state, simply because most of the time it is obsolete, and also maybe because one of these data could be the cause of the crash. This distinction is important to have a code without side effect (so much easier to debug and verify), and also to stick to the "let it crash" usage.

Comment: Why? Because our professor wants us to deal with failure in Erlang. So I guess you could assume that the process would have crashed, rather than died cleanly. We have to implement the 2048 game by using Erlang, where every tile in the 4 by 4 grid is a registered process. Depending on the command (up,down,left,right), those tiles have to communicate with each other to update their values, but the tiles can randomly be forced to close itself. So we learn how to deal with failure. We should respawn the tiles with the current value, as if they were never gone.

Comment: Check out this presentation: http://www.slideshare.net/torbenhoffmann90/2014-12ndcthinking It instructs how to design game of life, which is also cell based. Dealing with failure starts on slide 29. It is a little bit complex, but the solutions scales amazingly well.

Comment: It is a nice exercise, and you can still ask why. The role of each cell could be to know its location, its neighbors, apply the game rule in reaction to the player actions, and ensure the result is stored in mnesia. Then you could implement redundant mnesia tables to store the game progress, through a direct interface or maybe a global interface in order to synchronize all updates in a single atomic action at each round (to preserve game consistency). It depends on how you model the faults. a simple `Pid ! die` will be catch at a known place (save before die works) but `exit(Pid,kill)` won't.

Answer (score 0):

`sys:get_state/1` allows you to access the state of processes that are still running. If the processes are doing something important with the data contained in their state the data should be stored elsewhere as well - on disk, in a database, or in another process (message queue maybe?). **This is probably an architectural issue.** You should plan on individual processes crashing and you shouldn't need to pick through the  remains of a dead process to recover. You didn't mention supervisors and that may be something you should look into. Supervisors are an essential part of fault-tolerant and concurrent Erlang/OTP applications. Documentation on the supervisor behavior is available here: http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/supervisor.html

Answers to both questions: You should probably consider redesigning your application so that the supervisor handles restarting of processes and then possibly create another process to manage data/state that shouldn't be lost.

Comment: `sys` only works with proper OTP processes like `gen_server`. It doesn't work with any process. For example try in this in console: `sys:get_state(self()).`